# Android Studio doesn't show up my cpp header

Tags: c++, android-studio, cocos2d-x

I'm trying to build a game for Android using **Cocos2d-x** and Android Studio. I've imported `proj.android` to Android Studio and created additional `cpp` files, then I added these classes.

[image]

to `CMakeLists.txt`. As the result, I got.

[image]

`Definitions.h` file doesn't appear in Android Studio and I can't find the reason.

Comment: It builds normally, but I can't see the file in Android Studio.

Comment: the same for me. i've found that it is 'normally' behavior https://www.gamedev.net/forums/topic/684140-unable-to-see-header-file-in-android-studio/?tab=comments#comment-5321641

Comment: I also have this issue, Android Studio doesn't seem to show individual .h files (without .cpp), but it doesn't affect build at all.